# haproxy backend limit not going higher than 1000

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, tcp, load-balancing, haproxy

I have my backend `maxconn` set to `5000` but the limit will not go up from `1000`. The global maxconn in the screenshot is 2k. I changed that to 10, but the backend limit will not go above 1k
[image]

here is my config

```
global
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  log /dev/log local0
  log-tag loggy
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon
  quiet
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats mode 777 level admin
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  maxconn 10000

defaults
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 60s
  timeout server 120s
  timeout tunnel 1h
  log global
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option redispatch
  stats uri /haproxy-status

frontend http-in
  default_backend servers
  bind *:80
  maxconn 10000
  acl is_record_http hdr(Upgrade) -i websocket
  use_backend servers-record if is_record_http
  use_backend servers if !is_record_http

frontend httpssl-in
  default_backend servers-ssl
  bind *:443
  maxconn 10000
  use_backend servers-ssl-record if { req_ssl_sni -i something.something.com }
  use_backend servers-ssl if { req_ssl_sni -i www.something.com }
  tcp-request inspect-delay 10s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  mode tcp


backend servers
  server server-app something.com

backend servers-record
  server server-record something.com

backend servers-ssl
  server server-app-ssl something.com
  acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
  acl serverhello rep_ssl_hello_type 2
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if clienthello
  stick on payload_lv(43,1) if clienthello
  stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello
  maxconn 5000
  mode tcp
  stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m
  tcp-response content accept if serverhello

backend servers-ssl-record
  server server-record-ssl something.com
  acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
  acl serverhello rep_ssl_hello_type 2
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if clienthello
  stick on payload_lv(43,1) if clienthello
  stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello
  maxconn 5000
  mode tcp
  stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m
  tcp-response content accept if serverhello
```

Comment: after raising front end to 20k the backend limit rises to 2k. Why is it only able to take 1/10 of the frontend limit?

Comment: What happens if you actually put the `maxconn` directive on the actual `server` line of the config?

Comment: That max_sessions_limit keeps set at 1/10 of frontend connections limit

Answer (score 0):

Per answers [here](https://serverfault.com/a/907441/140709), [here](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/backend-sessions-limit-200/1661) and [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg26566.html) and the [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-fullconn):

The backend limit is the value of `fullconn` which is by default 10% of `maxconn` of frontend. You should only have to worry about the `fullconn` parameter if you have set up `minconn` parameter in server lines (to use dynamic `maxconn`), otherwise you can ignore it.

So the maximum amount of connections is sum of `maxconn` of your backed values which will only be limited if the global `maxconn` value is lower than the sum of the backend values.